# Getting a message 'Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection', how to solve?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

This is actual message:

> **Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: createDatabaseTable. This is
> currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an
> invalid configuration option to a Connection.**

application not respond after getting this message.

I'm using sequelize & as a conncection driver using mysql2, using express-session & as a session store package using express-mysql-session.

Session store configuration code is:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise')

const options = {
    host: config.get('db_host'),
    port: config.get('db_port'),
    user: config.get('db_user'),
    password: config.get('db_password'),
    database: config.get('db'),
    createDatabaseTable: false,
    schema: {
        tableName: 'sessions',
        columnNames: {
            session_id: 'sessionId',
            expires: 'sessionExpire',
            data: 'info'
        }
    }
}
const connection = mysql.createPool(options);
const sessionStore = new MySQLStore({}, connection);

session({
    secret: config.get('secret'),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore
  }),
```

If use more property such as clearExpired, expiration etc. I'm getting warning message for every property. So I remove createDatabaseTable property from options, also application not running. In this situation what should I do?

Comment: The options object being passed into createPool() should only contain valid [connection options](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options) and/or [pool options](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pool-options)

Comment: @nnichols Sequelize now prefer to use mysql2. **express-mysql-session** provide various option & i want to create **custom session schema**. express-mysql-session gives this opportunity.

Comment: Yes, and the [mysql2 -> API and Configuration docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#api-and-configuration) all but redirect to the Node MySQL docs for config. The options you pass to **express-mysql-session** are not the options you pass to mysql2! You have copied the example config for **MySQLStore** from [Custom database table schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session#custom-database-table-schema).

Comment: @nnichols. I don't understood which pool option can i use from mysql for create custom schema, modify schema columns name, set session expire time. If you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your options for mysql2 from the options for MySQLStore. Not tested, but should be something like -

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
const mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

const dbOptions = {
    host: config.get('db_host'),
    port: config.get('db_port'),
    user: config.get('db_user'),
    password: config.get('db_password'),
    database: config.get('db')
};

const storeOptions = {
    createDatabaseTable: false,
    schema: {
        tableName: 'sessions',
        columnNames: {
            session_id: 'sessionId',
            expires: 'sessionExpire',
            data: 'info'
        }
    }
};

const connection = mysql2.createPool(dbOptions);
const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(storeOptions, connection);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false }
}));

// simple test
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.views) {
        req.session.views++
    }
    else {
        req.session.views = 1
    }
    res.send('Session views: ' + req.session.views)
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Running`)
});
```

And this is the create statement for my sessions table -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
    `sessionId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `sessionExpire` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `info` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`sessionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

Comment: unfortunately not working.

Comment: application not respond.

Comment: yes, actually i'm not getting any warning message but not respond my application

Comment: yes, I'm not getting any warning message.

Comment: what was your output?

Comment: What’s necessary to use the sql script additionally for create session table when i define **storeOptions**. When you use your updated code & try to run. Application working properly?

Comment: If will define `createDatabaseTable: true` then no need to define custom schema options. & also no need to use sql script. am i right?

Comment: Opps, it's not working. Application not responding.